# My current fine-tuned BERT model saved on physical space takes 7GB of space. Is it normal for the model to take such large amount of space.?

Tags: tensorflow, neural-network, nlp

My fine-tuned BERT model for classification taking large amount of storage space, wanted to understand if it is normal or I am not saving the model in a correct manner

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's count the parameters of the model. For the BERT base model it is:

- embeddings: 30k word-piece embeddings with 768 dimensions = 23M
- 12 Transformer layers, each with:

  - feedforward layer with 2 projection 768 × 4 × 768 = 2.4M
  - projections queries, keys and values in self-attention for 12 heads = 12 × 3 × 768 × 768 = 21.2M
  - projection from 12 head context vector into a single context vector = 12 × 3 × 768 × 768 = 7.1M
  - this is 32.7M parameters per layer = 392.4M

This is 415.M parameters for the entire model. Standard floats in TensorFlow have 32 bits, i.e., 4 bytes, this gives you roughly 1.5 GiB only BERT parameters. You need some space for the model definition, you classifier also has some parameters. My estimate is that your saved model should be slightly over 2GiB.

Adam optimizer keeps momenta for all parameters, i.e., in the end, you save three numbers per parameter which makes the saved model three times bigger. This might be your case as well.

Comment: Is it possible that it could be normal if the author of the question is using BERT Large, which has 3x times the parameters of BERT Base.?

Comment: Yes, that is possible.

Comment: Thank @Jindřich for explaining, it does make sense, also I found out that saving multiple checkpoints in a major issue in my model taking this amount of space, while you are absolutely correct about bert model itself taking around 1.5GiB of space